# Ionic: Custom tab-bar background color on comment page?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Ionic 1.2

I'm trying to change the background color of the tab bar **on a specific screen** in my app where I have a text input sitting on top of the tab bar, similar to how Twitter's tab bar looks (see image below).

In other words, I want to change the background color of my tab bar from, say, black to white on a specific screen and otherwise keep the tab bar the default black color. The idea would be similar to adding a class to a specific screen to change the style of the tab bar.

Any thoughts? Any help much appreciated!

[image: Screenshot of Twitter app tab bar with comment box]

Comment: Did my answer helped you to solve the problem? If you need anything else i'm here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using **[ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)**.

[image]

1.) **tabs.html**

Add `ng-style="{'background-color': Color}"` inside `<ion-tabs>`.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-light" ng-style="{'background-color': Color}">

  //

</ion-tabs>
```

2.) **controllers.js**

Add [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) as dependency and following [$ionicView](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/) to each controller (use same color in controllers where you have a text input sitting on top of the tab bar). For each tab choose different color.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
  $rootScope.Color = 'red';
  });
```

3.) **style.css**

```
.tabs {
   background-color: inherit;
}
```

[image]